# How to store return value of function in multiprocessing process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am writing a python program which executes functions in parallel manner. Here is code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def sqr(args):
    results = []
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i)
    return results

def cube(args):
    results = []
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i*i)
    return results

def main():
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    p1 = Process(target=sqr, args=(data,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=cube, args=(data,))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


main()
```

I don't have idea how can I get return values of `sqr` and `cube` functions.

I have tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from queue import Queue

def sqr(args, q):
    results = []
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i)
    q.put(results)

def cube(args, q):
    results = []
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i*i)
    q.put(results)

def main():
    q = Queue()
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    p1 = Process(target=sqr, args=(data, q))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=cube, args=(data, q))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print(q.get())

main()
```

This program will suspend for infinite time. I don't understand what's going wrong here?
can anybody help me, how can I store return result of function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu OS

Comment: You should be using [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), if you want to approach your problem this way. `queue.Queue` is for multi threading. Now your original process will sit infinitely waiting for data in `q.get()`, since the other **processes** are writing to their own copies of the queue.

Comment: Your code is not fully clear, help me understand what is your goal. Do you want to compute in parallel the cube of a list of numbers and store the results in a single list?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Testing locally, using the MP queue hasn't fixed the issue for me

Comment: I have neither Python 3 or Linux handy to test, but you have `p1.join()` after you start `p2`. Moving the `join` above `p2 = Process(target=cube, args=(data, q))` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @roganjosh Just tested with `multiprocessing.Queue` and the original code worked just fine. @Amit by Ubuntu OS you mean a real Linux, or the Windows 10 Bash for plah plah?

Comment: @alec Yes I want to computer sqr and cube in parallel.

Comment: @llja I mean real Linux

Comment: Ok. Was asking since you always call `main()` at the end of your module. This would cause trouble in Windows since it cannot fork, but must create a new process from scratch and then import the module etc., though I'm not entirely sure if that applies to that Windows 10 Bash thing. Usually you'd wrap such calls in a guard such as `if __name__ == '__main__':` just to be sure. Also on Ubuntu here, and as said before if I replace the `queue.Queue` with `multiprocessing.Queue`, it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I would use multiprocessing.Pool, to execute sequentially cube() and sqr() and then parallelize for each input using Pool.map(). This will eliminate the need for Queue and it simplifies the main functions.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def sqr(n):
    return (n*n)

def cube(n):
    return (n*n*n)

def main(n):
    return (cube(n),sqr(n))

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    inputs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    results = p.map(main, inputs)

print(list(results))

[(1, 1), (8, 4), (27, 9), (64, 16), (125, 25), (216, 36), (343, 49), (512, 64), (729, 81)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the results global? This should work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

results = []
def sqr(args):
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i)
    return results

def cube(args):
    for i in args:
        results.append(i*i*i)
    return results

def main():
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    p1 = Process(target=sqr, args=(data,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=cube, args=(data,))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


main()
```

Comment: Separate processes do not share the same `results` list as they have separate mem spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to share resources between processes:

1. File (e.g. pickle, cPickle, marshal, ...)
2. Shared memory (e.g. queue)
3. PIPE